# Transform Input String to Array of words without contracted article

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace, split

to make a functional searchbar that checks correspondence between element datatags and a search bar input field I need to modify the Input value into an array.

That part is ok, but I also need to get rid of contracted articles in the array. To do so I take out of the string what's between " " and " ' " before making an array out of it.
My problem is that it also gets rid of words between the first " " and the " ' ",

Any idea on how to do this?

Actual result : input "test test2 d'test3" becomes `["test", "test3"]`

Expected result : `["test", "test2", "test3"]`

HTML :

```html
<input type="text"  id="mainInputBar" >
```

JS :

```js
const Mainsearch = document.getElementById('mainInputBar');

string_to_array = function (str) {
     return str.replace(/ .*'/, ' ').trim().split(" ");
};

$('#mainInputBar').on('change keyup paste click', function () {
  console.log(string_to_array(Mainsearch.value))
});
```

```js
const Mainsearch = document.getElementById('mainInputBar');

string_to_array = function (str) {
     return str.replace(/ .*'/, ' ').trim().split(" ");
};

$('#mainInputBar').on('change keyup paste click', function () {
  console.log(string_to_array(Mainsearch.value))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="mainInputBar" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try matching only `a-z, A-Z, 0-9` using `\w`

**References**

- [RegExp Character classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes)
- [RegExp Advanced searching with flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags)

```js
const Mainsearch = document.getElementById('mainInputBar');

string_to_array = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/ \w*'/g, ' ').trim().split(" ");
};

$('#mainInputBar').on('change keyup paste click', function() {
  console.log(string_to_array(Mainsearch.value))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mainInputBar">
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I guesse I need to look up more about \w \d etc

Comment: For future readers, I justed noted, this works only for the first contracted article, if there's another one in the feild it will appear in the array. This doesn't bother me for my specific need of it though. (" hello d'aloo d'alllo" becomes ````[
  "hello",
  "aloo",
  "d'alllo"
] ````

Comment: @LucR that's because you have not added the global flag. documentation links added. check updated answer

Comment: thanks a lot,  just managed to put the global flag at the right place. I'm gonna start reading that doc right !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), you can use a mix of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to do the job.

I create a function call stringToArray which gets the job done:

```js
function stringToArray(str) {
  if(str) {
    return str.split(" ").map((element) => {
        const finalString  = element.split("'")[1];
        return finalString ? finalString : element;
    });
  }
}

const Mainsearch = document.getElementById('mainInputBar');

$('#mainInputBar').on('change keyup paste click', function () {
  console.log(stringToArray(Mainsearch.value))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="mainInputBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```js
const Mainsearch = document.getElementById('mainInputBar');

string_to_array = function (str) {
     console.log(str.replace(/.[\s]*'/, ' '));
     return str.replace(/ .[\s]*'/, ' ').trim().split(" ");
};

$('#mainInputBar').on('change keyup paste click', function () {
  console.log(string_to_array(Mainsearch.value))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="mainInputBar" >
```